# issue accessing the contentScript file when the tab url belongs to the file system

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

the following is a fragment of the `"main.js"` code.

My problem is that when I use the `"option 1" url` the code works perfectly
but when I use the `"option 2" url`, then the functions marked to be exported
on `"content-script.js"` (to be seen on `"page.html"`) are not properly seen on `"page.html"`.

I have all the necessary code to export and communicate things.
The key point is just on the pageUrl format. It seems that there
is some problem when using file system urls in the form of:

```
"file:///D:/page.html"
```

In cases as above (`file://`) the `"contentScriptFile"` is not included for some reason.

Do I have to make some modification on the security configuration of Firefox,
for example on: `"about:config"` area?

Any Idea?

```
// [option 1] pageUrl = "http://localhost:81/firefox_addon/page.html";
// [option 2] pageUrl = "file:///D:/page.html";

tabs.open({
    url: pageUrl,
});

var pageMod = pageMods.PageMod({
    include: ["*"],
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("content-script.js"),
    onAttach: startListening
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PageMod constructor, you will need to define the `file://` schema as well as the `*` wildcard.

```
var data = require('sdk/self').data;
var pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');

function startListening(){
  // noop
}

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: ['*', 'file://*'],
  contentScriptFile: [
    data.url('content-scripts.js')
  ],
  onAttach: startListening
});
```

This allows the PageMod module to include content scripts on `file://` schema's

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark an answer as valid if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

I know that content-scripts do not have the same-origin policy as scripts included by the originating document itself, however it could be that the same-origin policy *is* being applied due to the sensitive nature of file:// URIs.

You can try setting security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false in about:config.

You can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3A_URIs

Another possibility is that the add-on SDK is intentionally disabling content scripts due to the sensitivity of file:// URIs.

Either way, check the browser console and see if there are any relevant error messages.